# UniqueNationalId.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, validationattribute

I wrote a custom attribute:

```
public class UniqueNationalId : ValidationAttribute
 {
  private readonly UserService _userService;

public UniqueNationalId()
{
    _userService = new UserService();
}

protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (_userService.IsNationalIdExist(value.ToString()))
        return new ValidationResult("National code is available in the system");
    return null;
}
```

I use IsNationalIdExist method:

```
    public bool IsNationalIdExist(string nationalId)
    {
        var validateName = _user.FirstOrDefault
                            (x => x.UserId == nationalId);
        if (validateName != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
       // return false;
    }
```

class model :

```
[IsValidNationalId]
    [UniqueNationalId]
    public string NationalId { get; set; }
```

Error gives the following

at UniqueNationalId.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)

What changes should I make ?????

Comment: Can you please post the complete error; this seems to be only a part of the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to return `ValidationResult.Success` if the validation succeeds and an error message if not, i.e.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (_userService.IsNationalIdExist(value.ToString()))
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    else
        return new ValidationResult("National code is not available in the system");
}
```